# Error :"Error:The user does not exist or is not unique " when add user in AD

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want add user in ActiveDirectory.

I use this code

```
private SPUser CreateUser(string strLoginName, string strEMail, 
 string strName, string strNotes, string strSiteURL)
{
SPUser spReturn = null;
SPSite spSite = null;
SPWeb spWeb = null;

try
{
//Open the SharePoint site
spSite     = new SPSite(strSiteURL);
spWeb     = spSite.OpenWeb();

//Assign role and add user to site
SPRoleAssignment spRoleAssignment = 
    new SPRoleAssignment(strLoginName, strEMail, strName, strNotes);
//Using Contribute, might need high access
SPRoleDefinition spSPRoleDefinition = 
    spWeb.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]; 

spRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(spSPRoleDefinition);
spWeb.RoleAssignments.Add(spRoleAssignment);

//Update site
spWeb.Update();
spReturn = spWeb.AllUsers[strLoginName];
}
catch(Exception)
{ 
}
finally
{
spWeb.Close();
spSite.Close();
 }

 return spReturn;
  }
```

when  **spWeb.RoleAssignments.Add(spRoleAssignment);** 
error :"Error:The user does not exist or is not  unique "

**EDIT**

The following worked for me:

```
 SPUser user = spWeb.EnsureUser(strLoginName);
 SPRoleAssignment spRoleAssignment = 
 new SPRoleAssignment(user);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will only grant Contribute access to an existing Active Directory user.

If you really want to create a new Active Directory user, see [Create Active Directory user in .NET (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298449/create-active-directory-user-in-net-c).